# Can I avoid the repeated allocation of a Vec in a for loop?

Tags: performance, rust, allocation

I want to avoid an allocation inside a loop:

```rust
use std::time::Instant;

/// calculate the sum of the squares of the elements in `numbers`
fn sum_of_squares(numbers: Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    numbers.iter().map(|x| x * x).sum()
}

fn main() {
    // start the timer
    let start = Instant::now();

    // "benchmark" the function 'sum_of_squares' by executing it a couple of times.
    for _ in 1..1000 {
        // Here I want to avoid the alloction.
        // This causes an ALLOCATION, wasting time the code could have spent calculating sum_of_squares D;
        let testcase: Vec<i32> = vec![4; 16];

        // here the actual work, I am interested in measuring, happens.
        sum_of_squares(testcase);
    }

    let elapsed_time = start.elapsed();
    println!("1000 sum_of_squaress in: {:?}", elapsed_time);
}
```

I want to spend the maximum of the time in the for loop calculating the sum of squares, so I would like to put the line `let testcase: Vec<i32> = vec![4; 16]` outside of the loop such that the only thing happening in the loop is adding together squares.

The problem is that the variable `testcase` is moved into the function `sum_of_squares`. When I put `let testcase = ...` outside of the loop, the borrow checker complains because after the
first iteration of the for loop, the variable testcases is no longer around.

Even if the time to allocate `testcase` is negligible, I would really like to know if I can avoid to allocate in each iteration of the loop.

### What I am not looking for

- I could rewrite `sum_of_squares` to take a reference as an argument instead of taking ownership of `testcase`, but I wonder whether there is another way that does not require me to change `sum_of_squares`.
- Another alternative would be to time the individual calls to `sum_of_squares` and then add up each elapsed time, but I am curious if there is a way where I can move the allocation out of the loop and, through some magic, pass `testcase` to `sum_of_squares`.

### What I am looking for

```rust
fn main() {
    // start the timer
    let start = Instant::now();

    // This where I want to put the definition of testcase
    let testcase: Vec<i32> = vec![4; 16];

    // "benchmark" the function 'sum_of_squares' by executing it a couple of times.
    for _ in 1..1000 {

        // * magic * to pass testcase to sum_of_squares
    }
}
```

### Sidenotes

- I am looking at the assembly in radare2 to see whether the program allocates in the loop.
- This question came up when I was working on making my MD5 implementation faster.  I challenged myself to a race against `openssl speed md5`. As my actual code is too big too post here I have come up with this example.

Comment: Can you or cant change `sum_of_squares` signature?

Comment: *I could rewrite sum_of_squares to take a reference as an argument instead of taking ownership of testcase, but I wonder whether there is another way that does not require me to change sum_of_squares.* - Sorry, but no - with the hard constraints you've set out, it cannot be done. If `sum_of_squares` is dead-set on destroying the allocation it receives, how would the caller hope to reuse it? Note that `sum_of_squares` taking `&[i32]` would make it no less performant because it would receive a reference/length pair, **not** a reference to the `Vec` (that would be `&Vec<i32>`).

Comment: I can but I am just curious wether there is an alternative way! That is why I am asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to pass and retake the owned `testcase`, but you would need to return it from the `sum_of_squares` function:

```rust
use std::time::Instant;

/// calculate the sum of the squares of the elements in `numbers` 
fn sum_of_squares(numbers: Vec<i32>) -> (i32, Vec<i32>) {
    (numbers.iter().map(|x| x*x).sum(), numbers)
}

fn main() {

    // start the timer 
    let start = Instant::now();

    let mut testcase: Vec<i32> = vec![4; 16];
    
    // "benchmark" the function 'sum_of_squares' by executing it a couple of times.
    for _ in 1..1000 {

        // here the actual work, I am interested in measuring, happens.
        let (_, nums) = sum_of_squares(testcase);
        testcase = nums;

    }

    let elapsed_time = start.elapsed();
    println!("1000 sum_of_squaress in: {:?}", elapsed_time);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=986f0a3cceb3166c1fca563ed1971ba7)

Comment: Or even better, `T: AsRef<[u8]>`.

Comment: [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)

Comment: @orlp, yeah, but lets get the OP assimilate concepts one by one :)

Comment: I did not think of that. Will definitely consider this as an alternative to changing the signature to a reference. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

*define the* `numbers: Vec<i32>` *as* Singleton *inside the function*
there are two possibilities to do this: `std::sync::Once` and the `lazy_static` macro
I prefer the later, because the Singleton is capsulated (means not outside the function visible)
(a change from the `Vec` to eg. a `RangeInclusive` solution would bring about a further speed advantage)

```
extern crate lazy_static;

fn sum_of_squares() -> i32 {
    lazy_static! {
        static ref NUMBERS: Vec<i32> = vec![4; 16];
    }
    NUMBERS.iter().map(|x| x * x).sum()
}
```

*(Your timing method is only suitable for an approximate assessment of the performance and does not replace a benchmark)*

Comment: there no reason in your code to not use an array

Comment: Correct. But I think the OP wanted to stick with the `Vec`, perhaps for some calculations.